# df with more than one field support?

Tags: solr, lucene

Is there any way to match more than one field in df in SOLR?

I have a use case where I want to search a field on two different fields if field is not specified in SOLR.

```
category:"text" OR ui_category:"text"
```

Is there any way to have more than one default field in SOLR?

Comment: I think you'll have to use (e)dismax and `qf` in that case - `edismax` supports the regular lucene syntax as well, so it might fit your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible with `dismax/edismax` parser.

Have `q` as your term to be searched. In this case it is `text`

Then specify list of fields that needs to be checked for the term in `qf`

`qf:category ui_category`

One good thing is that you can specify the boosting factor for the fields in `qf`

`qf:category^3 ui_category^0.5`